# SQL query to find the duplicates and compare the last two lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We have a database backup copied weekly to a specific location.

A SQL Server Agent job was setup to restore the DB from that specific location.
If for some reason, the backup copy process has not worked, existing copy is not replaced. SQL Server Agent job is restoring the last week's backup copy.

I am running this query to find out if the "Backup_set_id" has changed:

```
select * 
from [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]
where destination_database_name = 'DB Name'
order by restore_history_id desc
```

This will populate the Backup_set_id and other things.If the last two values for the Backup_set_id is not changed, I know the copy process is not worked.

Could you please help me with SQL script to setup a SQL agent job weekly to verify the Backup_set_id. If the last two rows of the Backup_set_is not changed,i can get the email notification ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you clarify the correct column name? In your question you have stated `Backup_Set_ID` but in your query you have put `Restore_history_ID`

Comment: If you want to get notified when restore process not done, you can know this at the Backup copy process stage fail only. Configure Job alert when it get fails.

Comment: "backup_set_id"  is the column name.( We also have on other column with a name restore_history_id (Unique). Restore job always successful. Because restore job takes what ever the backup set is available in the backup location(It doesn't check the date stamp of the backup. Our problem is if the backup copy is not modified, restore job is restoring with the old backup copy.

Comment: Can you post the DDL or some sample data. This is easy but impossible to write a query when the column names are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

This query counts unique values in the `restore_history_id`  ID column.

If this query returns any rows, it means it is a duplicate `restore_history_id` value.

You could automatically query this information with your own application and use the results to determine whether to send email or not.

```
SELECT restore_history_id, COUNT(restore_history_id) FROM [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]
WHERE destination_database_name = 'DB Name'
GROUP BY restore_history_id
HAVING COUNT(restore_history_id) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that.That query gave me the results  3 duplicate sets. Currently am running similar query to find the duplicates manually. I would like to know. If the SQL query returns any rows (there are duplicate backup sets), SQL agent job should raise an error and fail the job. IF the SQL query did not return any query results( no duplicates),  SQL agent job should complete the job successfully.

Comment: A sql Querry to compare the last two rows of backup_set_id FROM [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory] table. if the last two rows of the Backup_set_id results are same. Then SQL Agent should raise an error and fail the SQL job.

Answer (score 0):

```
--compare the two ID's You may need to change what you are ordering by to keep the data in order

declare @ct int
set @ct = 
    (select sum(CT) from
    (select top 2 case when lead(backup_set_id) over (order by restore_history_id) = backup_set_id then 1 else 0 end as CT
    from 
    restorehistory))

IF @ct = 1 --this means the last two IDs were the same

    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = 'Your Profile Name',
            @recipients = 'you@domain.com',
            @subject = 'Status Update',
            @body = 'The process did not work'

            --or just raise an error

        RAISERROR('There are duplicate records',16,1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        --do something else... or don't
    END
```

Comment: Am getting the following error : Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Edited @user1386445  I forgot to sum it

Comment: @user1386445  did that fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I Got this Error this time : Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. Try the edit i just posted @user1386445

Comment: Am still getting some syntax error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'. ---  restorehistory)). May be you can ignore the restore_history_id ,just compare the last two results of backup_set_id ? if there is a duplicate backup_set_id then raise error.